# GCM send-to-sync message gets to client with no data

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm sending a GCM send-to-sync message from the MessageEndpoint of the Appengine server that looks like this:

```
Message msg = new Message.Builder()
  .collapseKey("collapse-key-1")
  .timeToLive(600)
  .delayWhileIdle(true)
  .addData("key1", "val1")
  .addData("key2", "val2")
  .build();
```

When I get the message at the `onMessage()` of the GCMIntentService of the client app, I get a bundle that contains `"collapse_key=do_not_collapse"`, the `"collapseKey=collapse-key-1"` appears in the `"message"` key and the data `("key1", "val1", "key2", "val2")` appears nowhere.

The `onMessage()` looks like that:

```
     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
     if (bundle != null) {
        String key;
        Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            key = it.next();
            Log.d(it.toString(), key);
        }
    }
```

Also, when trying to look into the `Bundle` in the `Expressions` window in Eclipse, I see only what I have described, no data in there.

Any idea what has gone bad here?

Comment: Can you post your codes at the `onMessage()` method about parsing the bundle?

Comment: @ztan Edited the question, hope it is clearer now. Thanks! :)

Comment: You might want to check out this link: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-send and this tutorial about Message.Builder(); http://javapapers.com/android/android-device-to-device-messaging-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-via-http/

Comment: @ztan Thanks. I'm trying to send from the server and get the message on the device. Aren't the links about device-to-device and device to server? Also, Isn't the way I work with Message.Builder OK?